# Why is async task cancelled in a refreshable Modifier on a ScrollView (iOS 16)

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

I'm trying to use the refreshable modifier on a Scrollview in an app that targets iOS 16. But, the asynchronus task gets cancelled during the pull to refresh gesture.

Here is some code and an attached video that demonstrates the problem and an image with the printed error:

ExploreViemModel.swift

```
class ExploreViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var randomQuotes: [Quote] = []
    
    init() {
        Task {
            await loadQuotes()
        }
    }
     
    @MainActor
    func loadQuotes() async {
         
        let quotesURL = URL(string: "https://type.fit/api/quotes")!
        
        do {
            let (data, urlResponse) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: quotesURL)
            guard let response = urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse else { print("no response"); return}
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                let quotes =  try JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: data)
                randomQuotes.append(contentsOf: quotes)
            }
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error)
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func clearQuotes() {
        randomQuotes.removeAll()
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var exploreVM = ExploreViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            ExploreView()
                .environmentObject(exploreVM)
                .refreshable {
                    exploreVM.clearQuotes()
                    await exploreVM.loadQuotes()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Explore.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExploreView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var exploreVM: ExploreViewModel
 
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 140.0), spacing: 24.0)], spacing: 24.0) {
                    ForEach(exploreVM.randomQuotes) { quote in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("\(quote.text ?? "No Text")")
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("\(quote.author ?? "No Author")")
                                .font(.caption)
                        }
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 144.0)
                        .border(Color.red, width: 2.0)
                        
                    }

                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Explore")
        }
 
    }
}
```

[image: Cancelled Task]

[image: Printed Error]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `exploreVM.clearQuotes()` you cause the `body` to redraw when the array is cleared.

`.refreshable` also gets redrawn so the previous "Task" that is being used is cancelled.

This is just the nature of SwiftUI.

There are a few ways of overcoming this, this simplest is to "hold-on" to the task by using an `id`.

**Option 1**

```
struct ExploreParentView: View {
    @StateObject private var exploreVM = ExploreViewModel()
    //@State can survive reloads on the `View`
    @State private var taskId: UUID = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ExploreView()
                .refreshable {
                    print("refreshable")
                    //Cause .task to re-run by changing the id.
                    taskId = .init()
                }
            //Runs when the view is first loaded and when the id changes.
            //Task is perserved while the id is preserved.
                .task(id: taskId) {
                    print("task \(taskId)")
                    exploreVM.clearQuotes()
                    await exploreVM.loadQuotes()
                }
        }.environmentObject(exploreVM)
    }
}
```

If you use the above method you should remove the "floating" `Task` you have in the `init` of the `ExploreViewModel`.

**Option 2**

The other way is preventing a re-draw until the url call has returned.

```
class ExploreViewModel: ObservableObject {
    //Remove @Published
    var randomQuotes: [Quote] = []
    
    init() {
        //Floading Task that isn't needed for option 1
        Task {
            await loadQuotes()
        }
    }
     
    @MainActor
    func loadQuotes() async {
        
        let quotesURL = URL(string: "https://type.fit/api/quotes")!
        
        do {
            let (data, urlResponse) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: quotesURL)
            guard let response = urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse else { print("no response"); return}
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                let quotes =  try JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: data)
                randomQuotes.append(contentsOf: quotes)
                print("updated")
            }
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error)
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        print("done")
        //Tell the View to redraw
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
    
    func clearQuotes() {
        randomQuotes.removeAll()
    }
}
```

**Option 3**

Is to wait to change the array until there is a response.

```
class ExploreViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var randomQuotes: [Quote] = []
    
    init() {
        Task {
            await loadQuotes()
        }
    }
     
    @MainActor
    func loadQuotes() async {
        
        let quotesURL = URL(string: "https://type.fit/api/quotes")!
        
        do {
            let (data, urlResponse) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: quotesURL)
            guard let response = urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse else { print("no response"); return}
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                let quotes =  try JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: data)
                //Replace array
                randomQuotes = quotes
                print("updated")
            }
        } catch {
            //Clear array
            clearQuotes()
            debugPrint(error)
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        print("done")
    }
    
    func clearQuotes() {
        randomQuotes.removeAll()
    }
}
```

Option 1 is more resistant to cancellation it is ok for short calls. It isn't going to wait for the call to return to dismiss the ProgressView.

Option 2 offers more control from within the ViewModel but the view can still be redrawn by someone else.

Option 3 is likely how Apple envisioned the process going but is also vulnerable to other redraws.

Comment: Had to go with option 1 cos it doesn't require lot of changes to the view model of my actual app. Option 3 is great but will require more code in my actual app because it has a "load more data" functionality. One thing to note is that  the refreshable code works with a List as is. I think Apple needs to do fix this.

Comment: @JobieJ that is interesting, I would report as a bug. It seems like `.refreshable` should have an "id" of its own that gets changed with the action.

Comment: Yeah. I think it's a bug. I've posted the same problem on apple developer forum. But I'm yet to get a reply esp from an Apple employee

Answer (score 8):

I've just run into this as well, I'm not sure why the behaviour of `.refreshable` is such.
My solution is to wrap the logic inside `.refreshable {}` with a new task that we then wait for the result.

```
.refreshable {
    await Task {
        exploreVM.clearQuotes()
        await exploreVM.loadQuotes()
    }.value
}
```

That way even though the refreshable Task gets cancelled, there's nothing to cancel the new task, so the new Task will run until it is finished.

One nice thing with this is that the refresh spinner should show until the new task is finished.

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP and this solution worked best for me - it actually keeps the loader on the screen until completion. Feel like this is the best answer.

Are there any downsides of this approach to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap method to unstructured task like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var exploreVM = ExploreViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            ExploreView()
                .environmentObject(exploreVM)
                .refreshable {
                    exploreVM.clearQuotes()
                    // Lifecycle task
                    Task {
                        await exploreVM.loadQuotes()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason this would "work" is because you are causing a leak.

Comment: May be, but before I found this "work" as you say, I try all your 3 options and no one work for me. Try to add to any of your "options" CoreData entities with @FetchRequest in View and you will be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Alamofire and I was getting *request explicitly cancelled (AFError.explicitlyCancelled)* errors on pull to refresh. Especially on iOS 16 but also 17 occasionally.

So I put the great answer of @Stu into a new view modifier.

```swift
extension View {
    /// Prevents cancellation of this task on body redraws
    /// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76305308/4846592
    func refreshableWithoutCancellation(action: @escaping () async -> Void) -> some View {
        self.refreshable {
            await Task {
                await action()
            }.value
        }
    }
}
```

It can be dropped in instead of `refreshable`

Answer (score -2):

The point of async/await and `.task` is to remove the need for a reference type. Try this instead:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var randomQuotes: [Quote] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ExploreView()
                .refreshable {
                    await loadQuotes()
                }
        }
    }

      func loadQuotes() async {
         
        let quotesURL = URL(string: "https://type.fit/api/quotes")!
        
        do {
            let (data, urlResponse) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: quotesURL)
            guard let response = urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse else { print("no response"); return}
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                randomQuotes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Quote].self, from: data)
            }
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error)
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)

            // usually we store the error in another state.
        }
    }
}
```